Generate service area using variable range values in ArcGIS Pro
I'm trying to generate service areas where each point location has different sized service areas, based on attributes at that location.
The input is a road network feature class and a point feature class (travel range column-km).

You can use the Cutoff parameter to manually set the same value(s) for every point (e.g. 1000, 2000, 5000). Is there a way to use an attribute field in the point layer as input that would say for Location A use 1000, 2000, 5000, but for Location B use 500, 1000, 2500 to define the service area cut-offs?

Clarification from the OP in a comment given on a now deleted (now irrelevant) answer: "my question is : instead of the cutoffs, we should be able to give the point shapefile column which has distance values. Cutoff values are given manually, if there is an option to give the point shapefile and a specific column which has distance values, that would help me. "

According to the help file cuttoffs are type Double and help page gives no indication that a fields can be used through the GUI. I would explore using model builder to build strings of "500, 1000, 2500" and feed that into the parameter, the whole model being driven by an iterator.

Got the solution, While importing facilities, we need to choose the column where we have the range values and choose the impedence of distance that we setup in travel attributes in the network data set properties.
